# Limit of a function to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find the limit of the following function.

lim$_{x\rightarrow\infty}$ $\dfrac{x^2 - 5x + 1}{2x + 3}$

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options here:

- Divide numerator and denominator by $\,x^2\,$ and evaluate the limit. $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{x^2 - 5x + 1}{2x + 3} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{1 - \frac 5x + \frac 1{x^2}}{\frac 2x + \frac 3{x^2}}\overset{\frac 10}\longrightarrow +\infty$$ 
  In short: since the highest exponent in the numerator is greater than the highest exponent in the denominator, we have that the limit of your function as $x \to \infty$ is $+\infty$.

Or

- Use L'Hopital: take your function $\,\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and evaluate the limit of $\,\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$.

Comment: L'Hospital will not work here I believe.

Comment: @GTXOC Yes it will:we have an indeterminate form $\infty/\infty$. Then applied once, and you get $\dfrac{\infty}{\text{constant}} \to \infty$. L'Hopital's isn't needed, but if used, it works.

Comment: @amWhy: Needs a TU =1

Comment: @user108287 Does this make sense?